# python evaluate commands in form of strings

Tags: python, functional-programming, symbols, evaluation

In Python I am trying to figure out how to evaluate commands given as strings in a program. For example, consider the built in math functions `sin`, `cos` and `tan`

Say I am given these functions as a list;

```
li = ['sin', 'cos', 'tan']
```

Now, I want to iterate over each element in the list and apply each function to a numeric argument:

```
x = 45
for func in li:
    func(x)
```

The above clearly will not work as func is a string and just shows the idea. In lisp I could make each function a quoted symbol and then evaluate similarly to the above (well in lisp syntax of course, but the idea is the same).

How is this done in python?

Thanks and let me know if you need more information!

Comment: You could make a dictionary to map the string names to their respective functions?

Comment: Whichever answer you choose, please don't use the `eval` one in production, especially if you get user input. Consider the user input `'import os; os.remove('/etc/passwd')'` or something similar...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the functions themselves:

```
from math import sin, cos, tan
li = [sin, cos, tan]
```

If you really need to use strings, create a dict:

```
funcs = {'sin': sin, 'cos': cos, 'tan': tan}
func = funcs[string]
func(x)
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a several options here, I've listed some of the better options below:

- If all of the functions come from the same module, you can use `module.getattr(func)` to access the function.  In this case sin, cos, and tan are all functions from math so you could do the following:

  ```
  import math

  li = ['sin', 'cos', 'tan']
  x = 45
  for func in li:
      x = getattr(math, func)(x)
  ```
- Create a dictionary mapping names to functions, and use that as a lookup table:

  ```
  import math

  table = {'sin': math.sin, 'cos': math.cos, 'tan': math.tan}
  li = ['sin', 'cos', 'tan']
  x = 45
  for func in li:
      x = table[func](x)
  ```
- Put the functions in your list directly:

  ```
  import math

  li = [math.sin, math.cos, math.tan]
  x = 45
  for func in li:
      x = func(x)
  ```

Comment: If one has already done `from math import *`, then would `globals()[func](x)` work?

Comment: Yes that would work, but in that case I still think it would be better to create a dictionary with a limited set of the expected mathematical functions, rather than allowing any arbitrary function that might be included in the namespace to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're getting these strings from something like user input, so you can't just change your input to be a list of functions, you have several ways to do this. One way would be to look up the functions in the `math` module:

```
import math

name = 'sin'
getattr(math, name) # Gives the sin function
```

Alternatively, you can build a dict mapping names to functions:

```
funcs = {'sin': math.sin, 'cos': math.cos, 'tan': math.tan}

funcs['sin'] # Gives the sin function
```

Answer (score 1):

If these are functions of a module (the ones of the example are functions of `math` module) you can use `getattr`:

```
import math
li = ['sin', 'cos', 'tan']
x = 45
for func in li:
    f = getattr(math, func)
    f(x)
```

If you don't need to be strings you can make a list of functions:

```
import math
li = [sin, cos, tan]
x = 45
for func in li:
    func(x)
```